# ractivejs table cancel operation

Tags: ractivejs

This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/84xp4jan/12/)

```
 cancel:function(event){
     this.set(event.keypath+".editing",false);
}
```

When I click the "cancel" button, because the two-way-binding,the data is actually updated,how to achieve the cancel operation?

There are other elegant way？

Comment: Well, you are controlling the editing mode with a variable. I don't think that there is shorter or elegant way then simple variable setting.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Your current solution seems fine to me. However if you want, you could use ractive.toggle() on ".editing" instead. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/84xp4jan/13/).

```
 toggleEdit:function(event){
     this.toggle(event.keypath+".editing");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a proxy event, you can directly call ractive methods when you bind an event:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" on-click="toggle(event.keypath + '.editing')">cancel</button>
```

If all you need for canceling is this, then calling a method directly reduces your code size (you don't need to define the proxy event) and improves readability.